# string replacement problems in mysqldb.exeute

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have a small problem. And i think I am f=doing something silly but can not figure it out

first : 
i want to fire a dynamically constructed sql on mysql from python. Its simple insert statement but the values can have double quotes and other special characters in them. So, i was not sure how to do this.
Then i came accross this thread - [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642283/python-mysqldb-error-what-is-causing-this)

according to this i tried the following code

```
def fire_statement(stmt, value_tuple=None):

    try:
        if value_tuple == None:
            cur.execute(stmt)
            return True
        else:
            v = tuple(value_tuple)                
            cur.execute(stmt % v)
            return True
    except Exception, ex:
        print ex
        print "Query: '"+stmt+"'"
        return False
```

I have to pass the dynamically created stmt and value_tuple in this function i have no other way as the column names and values both will depend on external conditions. qand one more piece of information is the passed value_tuple is originally a list.

Two conditions are occurring in this code, and alas none of the approaches work

condition-1: when value_tuple = ('269', '1', '69', '1096', '1', '3070801', 'BE', '1963', '6')
and stmt = INSERT INTO XXX (`NCLASS`, `CRECEIVE`, `SUBCAT`, `GDATE`, `ASSCODE`, `PATENT`, `COUNTRY`, `GYEAR`, `CAT`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
i am getting this error - not all arguments converted during string formatting

(obviously the line - cur.execute(stmt % v) is changed to cur.execute(stmt , v)) for this case.

condition-2: when value_tuple = ('269', '1', '69', '1096', '1', '3070801', 'BE', '1963', '6') and stmt = INSERT INTO XXX (`NCLASS`, `CRECEIVE`, `SUBCAT`, `GDATE`, `ASSCODE`, `PATENT`, `COUNTRY`, `GYEAR`, `CAT`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
it is throwing this error - (1054, "Unknown column 'BE' in 'field list'")
Query: 'INSERT INTO XXX (`NCLASS`, `CRECEIVE`, `SUBCAT`, `GDATE`, `ASSCODE`, `PATENT`, `COUNTRY`, `GYEAR`, `CAT`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'

it seems that it is not replacing at all. but if i do a print (stmt % v)  just before the cur.execute then the result shows as - INSERT INTO XXX (`NCLASS`, `CRECEIVE`, `SUBCAT`, `GDATE`, `ASSCODE`, `PATENT`, `COUNTRY`, `GYEAR`, `CAT`) VALUES (269, 1, 69, 1096, 1, 3070801, BE, 1963, 6)

Which is again obviously not right because it is not enclosing the string value within quotes. And i believe that this may be causing the error. for this i am badly stopped at the development cycle for a few hours now. Please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to pass the arguments using

```
cur.execute(stmt, v)
```

and not

```
cur.execute(stmt % v)
```

If you have

```
"INSERT INTO tab (col1, col2) VALUES (%s, %s)"
```

and you pass two strings `('val1', 'val2')` using `%`, it will become:

```
"INSERT INTO tab (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2)"
```

which is interpreted as column names, which obviously do not exist.

If you do

```
cur.execute(stmt, v)
```

it will be interpreted correctly as

```
"INSERT INTO tab (col1, col2) VALUES ('val1', 'val2')"
```

You can also use

```
print cur.mogrify(stmt, v)
```

to see the correctly formatted query as it could be executed in your DB.